# Equivalent of 'make' command for CodeBlocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am using Codeblocks in Windows 10. Earlier I used to compile only 1 file, so I would just press the 'Build' and 'Run' button on codeblocks.

But, this time there are separate files I need to compile separately (to .o format) and then link to form a single executable file which I need to run. How can I do this in CODEBLOCKS? (In UNIX/LINUX systems, I know this is the 'make' command; but I don't know how to do it here?)

Can anyone help me? I tried reading some help pages on CodeBlocks on the internet, but they were so complicated, I gave up.

Comment: Isn't it compiling the all files contained in the project same way as a single file?

Comment: Sorry, I am new user, so maybe I not understand you. Each of the individual files will not work on their own, only after linking them, can the load module be executable. It is parallel assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` isn't a compiler, and neither is CodeBlocks. `make` is just a command that runs other commands from a `Makefile`. The actual command that gets run is something along the lines of `gcc a.cpp b.cpp`, and it's the same command (or similar enough) that gets run when you build inside CodeBlocks. CodeBlocks should automatically build and link all of the source files that you add to your project. If you aren't seeing this happening, make sure you add them to the project inside of CodeBlocks and don't just put the files in the directory.